# XCode - The app ID "com.xxxxx.xxxxx" cannot be registered to your development team

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, xcode8

I'm giving maintenance in an application and it was developed in Ionic.

When I'm going to test it on the device I need to start Xcode on the version 8.3.3, but I logged in with my user and password but he still gives the error.

As we can see on the bellow image:

[image]

Anyone know why I can't register my ID? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Well, you can’t register the same app domain for two different teams. You either need to ask the app owner to add you to their team or change the app id.

Comment: @Losiowaty Traduzir
the administrator has already created a user in itunes connect to the application, and I added it to xcode and it still shows the error.

Comment: Have you tried changing the team then? Cause it seems that currently it is set to your personal team.

Comment: @Losiowaty it's the problem, i have only one option, that is My Personal Team, I can't change it.

Comment: Have you double checked that the other account is present in Xcode preferences? Can you choose it for other (i.e. empty) project?

Comment: The only account that appears is the account they created (Marco Sprea (Personal team)) I do not have any other account option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you validate if you were added to the project's development team?

Typically this error occurs when you are trying to add a project that you do not have access to.

Ask your project manager to validate this.

To understand how to manage your Developer Account Team, please use the link [Managing Your Developer Account Team](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html) from the Apple Develop docs.